# get specific image location from PixtureBox inside Panel

Tags: c#

I have a PixtureBox inside Panel in c#, and I am trying to get the image location when i click on a certain image location. So I am using mouse location to get x and y, when the mouse is hovering over the image. This works fine if the image size is less than the size of the panel (no sliding bar). As soon as I get an image bigger than the panel size, I will get sliding bar. However, i get the same location if i moved the slide bar down. Is there a better way to get the specific image location with or without the sliding bar? any help is much appreciated :)
[image]

Comment: Is this winforms or wpf?

Comment: You'll have to add the panel's AutoScrollPosition to the mouse position.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Mouse_Hover](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousehover(v=vs.100).aspx) event has a default EventArgs so it doesn't send the current mouse position when the event is invoked. The [Mouse_Move event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousemove(v=vs.100).aspx) does provide [the mouse location relative to the scroll position](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs(v=vs.100).aspx). If you store the location received in an Mouse_Move event from your PictureBox in  local variable the Hover event can then use that position.

The position is absolute to the origin of the control so it doesn't matter if the picturebox is scrolled inside a panel.

```
Point last;  // hold the last mousemove location

private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    // store the location in last
    last.X = e.Location.X;
    last.Y = e.Location.Y;
}

private void pictureBox1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // do whatever we want to do with the last location
    Trace.WriteLine(last);
}
```